# Fallo al reproducir video en flutter

Tags: python, flutter, dart, video, odoo

estoy intentado hacer un "sistema de streaming casero" el cual esta compuesto de una base de datos Postgresql, Odoo11(Python3.8) y Flutter(Dart).

La idea es crear un endpoint en Odoo por el cual obtengo la url del video asociado a la base datos:

## Controlador para obtener los datos del Video a partir de su id.

```
    @http.route(['/downloadVideoFile2/<int:partnerId>/<int:fileId>'], type='http', csrf=False, auth="public", cors="*")
def downloadVideoFile(self, partnerId, fileId):

    result = {}
    res = []
    msg = ''
    st = 400
    mainvideo = ""

    # Se verifica que el token sea correcto
    #verification = self.checkJWTToken(request, partnerId)

    #st = verification['status'] or 400
    #msg = verification['message']

    logger.info(st)
    logger.info(msg)
    
    logger.info('-------------------------------------HE ENTRADO-----------------------------------------------------')

    cr, uid, context, registry = request.cr, request.uid, request.context, request.registry

        
    # Obtenemos el id del paciente a partir del id del partner.
    patientId = self.getPatientIdThroughPartnerId(partnerId)
    # Obtenemos el id del clinical record a partir del id del paciente.
    clinicalRecordId = self.getClinicalRecordIdThroughPatientId(patientId)
    
    qry = [('id', '=', fileId)]
    #Sacamos la lista de archivos que tengan el mismo id del directorio
    filecontent = request.env['muk_dms.file'].sudo().search(qry).reference.data
    mainvideo = base64.b64decode(filecontent or '') 

    headers = [('Content-Type', 'video/mp4'),('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')]
   
        
    headers.append(('Content-Length', len(mainvideo)))
        
    return request.make_response(mainvideo, headers)
```

Lo importante es "mainvideo" que contiene información de un archivo mp4 en formato hexadecimal. Es el contenido de la respuesta. La url generada se ven de esta manera : http://localhost:8069/downloadVideoFile2/56/6

Ahora bien cuando ataco al endpoint desde Postman obtengo respuesta sin problema ninguno :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema aparece cuando intento reproducir el video desde flutter(Con un móvil virtualizado):

```
super.initState();
Map<String, String> mapa = {
  "Authorization": widget.jwtToken,
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Range": "bytes=0-"
};
Map<String, String> mapa2 = {
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Range": "bytes=0-"
};

BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
    BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
    "http://10.0.2.2:8069/downloadVideoFile2/56/6",
    videoFormat: BetterPlayerVideoFormat.other,
    headers: mapa2);
_betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(
    BetterPlayerConfiguration(),
    betterPlayerDataSource: betterPlayerDataSource);
```

}

Me salta este error: E/flutter (10051):

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
> E/flutter (10051):
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051): Playback error
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:579)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: java.io.EOFException
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.read(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:445)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.read(StatsDataSource.java:92)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorInput.readFromUpstream(DefaultExtractorInput.java:283)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorInput.readFully(DefaultExtractorInput.java:75)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.readAtomHeader(Mp4Extractor.java:335)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.read(Mp4Extractor.java:241)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.read(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:127)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1048)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):   Caused by: java.io.EOFException
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.skipInternal(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:751)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.read(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:441)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10051):       ... 11 more
> E/flutter (10051): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
> E/flutter (10051):

También decir que cuando son videos pequeños no fallan, solo con videos mas largos y además cuando pulso reiteradamente en intentar funciona.

No si alguien se ha topado con este problema o sabe como solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Código y mensajes de error como texto; si no, no se puede.

Comment: Ya, siento el contratiempo

Comment: En primer lugar, esto no es problema del servidor ya que este responde correctamente. El problema podría estar en como muestras los datos (de lo cual desconozo), si al hacerlo varias veces te funciona puede ser por que el servidor tarda en responder o que ha habido algún problema al interpretar la respuesta

Comment: @Christian muchas gracias por la información. También comentar que otras veces me salta con la excepción "Loading finished before preparation is complete", no se si esto puede ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré el problema, era al reproducirlo desde un dispositivo emulado. Cuando lo he probado desde un dispositivo físico me ha funcionado sin problema. Espero que esto pueda ayudar a alguien alguna vez :D .

Comment: puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta

Comment: De hecho, yo tengo el problema tanto en emulador como en dispositivo.